# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle Invalid mapping file on random requests

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

While deploying my `Symfony2` application to a shared webhosting platform, I noticed that on random requests, the webapplication returns a status code 500. 
When looking in the logs, the application complains about an invalid mapping file:

> *request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: Invalid mapping file 'FOS.UserBundle.Model.User.orm.xml' for class 'FOS\UserBundle\Model\User'.*

I can't seem to fix this problem, it doesn't happen on each request.